# Add public upstream source to azure feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

We would like to have

```
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
```

as an upstream sources for our org level azure artifact feed. As far as I understand we can only have public upstream sources from npm, nuget, maven and pypi.

Can anyone give any leads on how should we go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Artifacts supports only public package managers (npmjs.com, NuGet.org, Maven Central, and PyPI) as public upstream source.

Custom upstream sources are currently only supported for NPM.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

You can use JBoss Maven repositories directly in your builds by configuring Azure DevOps Pipeline. Example:

```
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'Maven Authenticate'
  inputs:
    MavenServiceConnections: central,MavenOrg
```

The MavenAuthenticate task updates the settings.xml file present in the agent users' .m2 directory located at {user.home}/.m2/settings.xml to add two entries inside the  element.

**settings.xml**

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>central</id>
    <username>centralUsername</username>
    <password>****</password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <id>MavenOrg</id>
    <username>mavenOrgUsername</username>
    <password>****</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

You should set the repositories in your project's pom.xml to have the same  as the name specified in the task for Maven to be able to correctly authenticate the task.

**pom.xml**

```
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/maven-authenticate?view=azure-devops#authenticate-maven-feeds-outside-your-organization

https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15170